# What is the present for getting all 123 cards in Botanicula?

Tags: botanicula

I got two presents for getting 107/123. What is the reward for collecting all 123 cards? (Is it the third present?)

[image: 123 cards]

Comment: I got 3 presents with 115/123. It was a light saber battle between lantern and a spider thingy. I want to know which cards I missed. I was really vigilant too...I guess I'll have to play again. :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the colors of the cards? Some of them are beige and some are brown. I got 113 cards but only 2 presents for the 1st play, but I'm not sure if I've made each creature "completely developed" . Just a thought!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear exactly how many cards are needed to get the third present, but getting 123 will should unlock it as proved with the pic below.  [In this forum post](http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php/topic,3767.0.html), a user states that they do not have the third present and have found 122 cards.  However Tom mentions above that he got the present without getting all 123, and [a comment on this guide](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2012/04/botanicula.php) agrees.  To your specific question, it also mentions the exact reward as:

> Got 3 gifts at the end (116 or 119/ 123), two of them were mentioned above. Third one is the beet root fighting the black parasite Jedi style :)

Which seems to agree with what Tom stated.

[image: 123 cards]

[Several](http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php/topic,3762.0.html) [sources](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=30444793) confirm that getting 123 cards *does not* award the Mythology achievement, as some suspected it might.