# How do I get the "Mythology" achievement?

Tags: botanicula

This achievement's details are murky. Who are the creatures I need to speak with for this achievement, and where are they? (Screenshots appreciated.) If this achievement was originally indeed bugged, what do I have to do in the new patch to get the achievement to register?

[image: mythology]

Comment: Answer is here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64028/3921

Comment: That answer says that the presents aren't related to "Mythology", not how to get it. Right?

Comment: Right. The links help figure it out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: There are **three lollipop creatures** who tell spider stories. **Talk to each**, and you can skip their cinematics if you want. Their locations:

- **Level 2 (collecting keys): below the resonant pods** ([YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8EmefzZhtM&hd=1&t=14m48s)) [image: lollipop 1]
- **Level 3 (collecting children): across the spider leg bridge** ([YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCDncuFG_Pw&hd=1&t=8m47s)) [image: lollipop 2]
- **Level 5 (collecting blue shards): beneath the infinite maze** ([YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uje_vNZhpy0&hd=1&t=8m16s)) [image: lollipop 3]

The achievement was bugged in the initial build, but it should pop upon patching and re-visiting the last lollipop in Level 5. (I didn't make saves my first game, so I couldn't test that myself.)